# "dnf system-upgrade reboot" stuck at booting: starting switch root

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I have tried to upgrade Fedora 24 to Fedora 26 via dnf. In the last step of this standard procedure is to call

```
$> sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

in order for the system to reboot and do the upgrade. By the system changes the root to the folder where the upgrade resides and this seems to be the problem. The last log you can read is:

> *Starting switch root ...*

This is a bind and you can only overcome this by changing Grub.

The machine is a Lenovo T450 laptop and the kernel is 4.11.12-100.fc24.x86_64

Has anybody a clue what can bring the Fedora 24 to start into the upgrade boot mode for installing Fedora 26?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions that's related with programming languages, so this is not the right place to ask question like that, try to ask your question [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/)

Comment: Sorry, but ask.fedoraproject.org has awkward conditions for joining there: Facebook, Yahoo, Google

Comment: @kladderradatsch Or a Fedora account or any OpenID. But you can also use https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange,com, both of which are in this site's network and where non-programming questions about Fedora are welcome.